# what does this configuration in apache mean?

Tags: apache, http, http-headers, vary

```
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
```

Can anyone give a detailed explanation for this?

Answer (score 11):

This uses Apache [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_headers.html) to append the value "User-Agent" to the Vary HTTP header, but only if the dont-vary environment is not set.

But what is the Vary header? See [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.44) which says

> The Vary field value indicates the set
>   of request-header fields that fully
>   determines, while the response is
>   fresh, whether a cache is permitted to
>   use the response to reply to a
>   subsequent request without
>   revalidation

If you deliver different HTML markup depending on the User-Agent header, you might use a Vary header with User-Agent in it to ensure that a caching proxy didn't serve content intended for browser X to browser Y.

Answer (score 4):

See the [Header directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_headers.html#header) in the mod_headers documentation.

This instructs the web server to **append** the new value of the **Vary** header to any previous value of the **Vary** header (separating the new value from the old one by a comma) or to create a new value for the **Vary** header.  The new value to be created or appended will be **user-agent**.  This header will only be created/appended if the **dont-vary** environment variable is undefined within the environment of the executing apache service.

To summarize, if the **dont-vary** environment variable *does not* exist, the server will issue out something like this:

```
Vary: ...,user-agent
```