# How can I get Apache gzip compression to work?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, gzip, mod-deflate

I can't get my site to use gzip compression.

I recently watched this [video](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/114-lets-do-simple-stuff-to-make-our-websites-faster/) by Chris Coyier over at css-tricks.com. In the video, he talks about enabling gzip compression to make websites run faster.

As per his instruction, I linked through to github via html5boilerplate.com, copied the gzip compression code from their .htaccess file, pasted it into my own, and uploaded it to my site.

I've tested it via gzipwtf.com and it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me with this?

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Trim www
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^orbitprint.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://orbitprint.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Gzip compression
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

  # Force deflate for mangled headers developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping/
  <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
      RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

  # Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
  <IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                  application/javascript \
                                  application/json \
                                  application/rss+xml \
                                  application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                  application/x-font-ttf \
                                  application/xhtml+xml \
                                  application/xml \
                                  font/opentype \
                                  image/svg+xml \
                                  image/x-icon \
                                  text/css \
                                  text/html \
                                  text/plain \
                                  text/x-component \
                                  text/xml
  </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you add some details about your server, e.g. the response headers? .htaccess just works for Apache servers, and if your Apache server doesn't have the mod_filter.c enabled, compression won't work.

Comment: Date: Tue, 11 Sep 2012 10:46:19 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0.63 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.0.63 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.9
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Try this :

```
####################
# GZIP COMPRESSION #
####################
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/plain text/xml application/x-javascript application/x-httpd-php
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip
```

Comment: Whats the Vary header for here? Is it necessary?

Comment: @MuratAyfer It has something to do with handling proxy servers.  I don't know the details.

Comment: @Oussama Is it possible to get an explanation of what each line does?

Comment: The "Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary" looks sketchy to me.  You should not "Vary" by user-agent unless you deliver different content to different User-Agents.  Otherwise it absolutely destroys your cache hit rate.  Basically, what the Vary header does is allow you to direct a Cache to consider the value of the request header named in the "Vary" header as a value that should be considered part of the cacheable request key, sort of like its part of the query args. Another discussion about this line:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970798/what-does-this-configuration-in-apache-mean

Comment: @jerryb - it's because he copy-pasted his answer from the internet... https://varvy.com/pagespeed/enable-compression.html

Answer (score 40):

It is better to implement it as in the snippet below.

Just paste the content below in your `.htaccess` file, then, check the performance using: [Google PageSpeed](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/), [Pingdom Tools](http://tools.pingdom.com) and [GTmetrics](http://gtmetrix.com/).

```
# Enable GZIP
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</ifmodule>

# Expires Headers - 2678400s = 31 days
<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 7200 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2678400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2678400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2678400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 518400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2678400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2678400 seconds"
</ifmodule>

# Cache Headers
<ifmodule mod_headers.c>
  # Cache specified files for 31 days
  <filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|swf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public"
  </filesmatch>
  # Cache HTML files for a couple hours
  <filesmatch "\.(html|htm)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesmatch>
  # Cache PDFs for a day
  <filesmatch "\.(pdf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
  </filesmatch>
  # Cache Javascripts for 31 days
  <filesmatch "\.(js)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, private"
  </filesmatch>
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: can i jsut add this in the root and it works for all the subfolders?

Comment: Why do you need both `ExpiresByType` and `Header set Cache-Control`?

Comment: I provide [full .htaccess code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29488825/4058484) for to pass `Enable compression` and `Leverage browser caching` on [Google PageSpeed Insight](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hyip.world%2F&tab=mobile):

Comment: one quick comment - its important to add type for jpg and jpeg

Answer (score 11):

Your .htaccess should run just fine; it depends on four different Apache modules (one per each `<IfModule>` directive). I guess one of the following:

- your Apache server doesn't have either mod_filter, mod_deflate, mod_headers and/or mod_setenvif modules installed and running. If you can access the server config, please check `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` (and the related Apache config files); otherwise, you can see which modules are loaded via `phpinfo()`, under the apache2handler section (see attached image); (**EDIT**) OR, you can open a terminal window and issue the command `sudo apachectl -M` that will list the loaded modules;
- if you get an http 500 internal server error, your server may not be allowed to use .htaccess files;
- you are trying to load a PHP file that sends its own headers (overwriting Apache'sheaders), thus "confusing" the browser.

In any case, you should double-check your server config **and** error logs to see what's going wrong. Just to be sure, try to use the fastest way suggested [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html) in Apache docs:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml
```

and then try to load a large textfile (preferably, clean your cache first).

(**EDIT**) If the needed modules are there (in the Apache modules dir) but aren't loaded,
just edit /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and add a [LoadModule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_so.html#loadmodule) directive for each one of them.

If the needed modules aren't there (neither loaded, nor in the Apache modules directory), I fear that the only option is reinstalling Apache (a complete version).

[image: phpinfo() apache2handler section]

Comment: My phpinfo() page doesn't have an apache2handler section, there is no mention of any of those modules in my httpd.conf file, and my apache modules folder seems to be quite sparse [link](http://goo.gl/ZRV4S). Is this typical?

Comment: No, it's not typical at all. I'd have expected some more modules to be there... is it a custom-packaged Apache?

Comment: I'm unsure, as this is the way Pixelinternet configured my server when I purchased it. I will contact my hosting company and see if they can help me get the modules I need installed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've worked it out. The mod_filter module requires Apache 2.1 or later. As I'm running 2.0 - the html5boilerplate code will never work for me!

Answer (score 9):

First of all **go to apache/bin/conf/httpd.conf** and make sure that mod_deflate.so is enabled.

Then go to the **.htaccess** file and add this line:

> SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

This should output all the content served as gzipped, i have tried it and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this problem using the same .htaccess configuration. I realized that my server was serving javascript files as `text/javascript` instead of `application/javascript`. Once I added `text/javascript` to the `AddOutputFilterByType` declaration, gzip started working.

As to why javascript was being served as `text/javascript`: there was an `AddType 'text/javascript' js` declaration at the top of my root .htaccess file. After removing it (it had been added in error), javascript starting serving as `application/javascript`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case i have used following code for enabling gzip compression in apache web server.

```
  # Compress HTML File, CSS File, JavaScript File, Text File, XML File and Fonts
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
```

I have taken reference from http://www.tutsway.com/enable-gzip-compression-using-htacess.php.

Answer (score 2):

If your Web Host is through C Panel Enable G ZIP Compression on Apache C Panel

Go to CPanel and check for software tab.

Previously Optimize website used to work but now a new option is available i.e "MultiPHP INI Editor".

Select the domain name you want to compress.

Scroll down to bottom until you find zip output compression and enable it.

Now check again for the G ZIP Compression.

You can follow the video tutorial also. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o0UDmcpGlZI

Answer (score 1):

In my case append only this line worked

`SetOutputFilter DEFLATE`

Answer (score 1):

**Enable compression via .htaccess**

For most people reading this, compression is enabled by adding some code to a file called .htaccess on their web host/server. This means going to the file manager (or wherever you go to add or upload files) on your webhost.

The .htaccess file controls many important things for your site.

The code below should be added to your .htaccess file...

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

Save the .htaccess file and then refresh your webpage.

Check to see if your compression is working using the [Gzip compression tool](https://varvy.com/tools/gzip/).

Answer (score 1):

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Insert filters
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-fastphp
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml

# Drop problematic browsers
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
```