# Apache gzip decompression

Tags: apache, gzip

How do you enable gzip decompression on the server side for requests.

I have seen response compression :
[How can I get Apache gzip compression to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367858/how-can-i-get-apache-gzip-compression-to-work)

But i couldn't find how to decompress a request to the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer :

In the root .htaccess file we will need to add this option to enable gzip decompression :

SetInputFilter DEFLATE

Here's the link : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html#enable
Check "Input Decompression"