# create rewrite rules only for one specific folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using WP site. its working fine. but i have one issue that is i have created a folder that is myfolder. In this folder i have created index.php file and added some JS and CSS files. so now my site link like below.

```
http://www.domain.com/myfolder/index.php?ver=52
```

Now i am working for increase site speed task. I want to enable gzip for this folder. so i think htaccess is the fine for increase speed of site. So i want to create rules only for this folder. when i will add condition rules only work for this folder then i can enable gzip for this folder. I am new in htaccess. So please let me know how i add condition and rewrite rules from htaccess from site htaccess file only for this folder.

Comment: Place folder specific code in `/myfolder/.htaccess`

Comment: Compression does _not_ automatically speed things up...

Comment: Search for `apache` and `gzip` or `deflate`, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/12367858/1741542