# multiple website hosted on single Apache web hosting with exact .htaccess code, one show gzip enabled while other website says gzip not enabled

Tags: .htaccess, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I have multiple website hosted on single Apache web server and when trying to resolve for gzip one website shows no error while the other website says compression not enabled in PageSpeed test. In .htaccess I have exact same code

Suggestion from this thread did not  helped.
[How can I get Apache gzip compression to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367858/how-can-i-get-apache-gzip-compression-to-work) and .htacess file contain exact same code as mentioned by Umut D.

Comment: Scripting languages such as PHP can disable gzip compression programmatically. You might want to look into the code that is hosted on those sites.

Comment: Hi @JonDiamond both are running on wordpress

Comment: Wordpress runs on PHP you can use phpinfo() to check most PHP settings.