# Magento - Error while enabling output compression (gzip)

Tags: magento, gzip

I have enabled gzip compression on magneto site, I verified that mod_deflate is installed & enabled (in Apache server).

But the problem is that when i uncomment the following line (2nd line) in the `.htaccess` file (in magneto root), i am getting a `"500 Internal Server Error"`

```
# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
# Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
```

Note that I have tested the site and the compression is working fine.

How could I solve this problem?
Could someone please clarify, if its OK if leave it commented?

Thank You

Comment: But that header isn't related to compression.

Comment: @clockworkgeek:: ya buddy its not, but i don't know what exactly its for and all the tutors related to enabling gzip have that uncommented, so that's why i have done that too!

Comment: It's to do with how [proxies cache pages](http://stackoverflow.com/q/970798/471559).  You only need it if your site serves different browsers with different content, for example if you have exceptions set in System > Configuration > Design.